# Unable to create sample application using Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new to PHP. downloaded "yii-1[1].1.4.r2429.zip" file. and try to create sample application using Yii PHP framework

Extracted yii-1[1].1.4.r2429.zip to this path.

C:\xampp\htdocs\yii on windows

and try to create sample application using this guidelines

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/quickstart.first-app

Run **yiic** on the command line as follows:

not working.

Please help

Comment: Not working isn't too talkative. Error messages, other symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you have PHP CLI (command line) installed and added to your Windows path.

Also, make sure you are running yiic.bat - the Windows script. The plain yiic script (no file extension) is a Unix shell script. You want something like this on Win:

```
YiiRoot/framework/yiic.bat webapp WebRoot/testdrive
```

If the .bat script doesn't work, call PHP directly to yiic.php, like so:

```
php path\to\yii\framework\yiic.php webapp path\to\www\ApplicationName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your might be able to benefit from XAMPP.  It comes pre-packaged and sets up a isolated environment for you, that way you don't have to go through installing php, apache and mysql.