# Getting Yii Command Line to Work

Tags: yii

I have recently set up Yii and when I try create an app via the command line I get a series of prompts requesting for dlls.

When I go through online resources I cant seem to find anyone who has this issue.

What configurations could I be overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this question: [Unable to create sample application using Yii Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3717821/50079).

You can also ditch the Yii command line tools to create an application and do it by hand though. You only need to do it once (the second time you know that it's dead easy, so it's better to do by hand).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have PHP installed and in your environment path.

Answer (score 0):

It's very dependent on what the errors are and how you setup your system.

If you're on Windows I'd recommend using a system lie [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

And when you have php in your environment path, it's also good to use full paths in the command line, for example:

php C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/framework/yiic webapp C:/xampp/htdocs/new_name_test