# running yiic from commandline fails after necessairy steps have been taken

Tags: yii, cmd

I'm trying to install a Yii application with the latest framework to date on wampserver2.2. 
I edited the .bat file to match the directory of my php /bin folder and added this as a value to the path variable. 
However I seem to be unable to run yiic from the commandline. Im trying this on a windows 7 professional OS but to no avail. If i fire up yiic.php it opens the file in a notepad window. If I try to run the .bat file, the cmdline returns that it can not open the input file c:\wamp\framework\yiic

What should I do to make yiic run from the commandline? I think I completed all the necessairy steps but could be easily overlooking something.

If someone could come up with an answer that would be great.

Comment: As a workaround: If you can access your PHP interpreter on the command line you can execute yiic, like $> php -f c:\wamp\framework\yiic.php webapp \path\to\somewhere

Comment: This is it. The application created my testapplication. Thanks for the workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure you are running `yiic.bat`, and not just `yiic` (which is the Linux shell script). There are two files in the directory, and your error (`can not open the input file c:\wamp\framework\yiic`) looks like you are using just `yiic`, the Bash script.
2. As @schmunk mentioned in the comment on the question, you can just call yiic.php directly with the PHP CLI. That is what the `yiic.bat` script is doing for you. :)

   C:\wamp\framework> php yiic.php webapp C:\wamp\htdocs\myproject

I answered a similar question here that covers the same stuff:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3728454/164439